# show parent in child screen django admin python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to python django and we decide to develop an application with this framework 
for developing the admin we faced some issues here's a snippet of my code the models is like :

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

And in the corresponding tables in database table Product has a foreign-key reference to Category (category_id)

In admin.py file I have :

```
 class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name','description'];

 class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fieldsets = [
             (None,{'fields':['name']}),
             ('Description',{'fields' : ['description']})
             ]
   inlines = [ProductInline]
```

When I need to insert a product into the database via the django admin panel there is no field to select the category and I received the following message :

```
"Column 'category_id' cannot be null"
```

where am I making mistake? how do I edit my code so that in admin panel it provides a dropdown or something to select its parent(In this case category)

Comment: Did you add any categories first? Also, where is the class definition for `ProductInline`?

Comment: I didn't put the whole file here in order to keep question short enough and only provide necessary information, that works fine I can easily insert category via admin the issue is with Prodcut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the "fields" option in your ProductAdmin. You might be confusing "fields" with "list_display"? Try

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name','description']
```